# Where do baby daemons come from?

Tags: parallel-universe, his-dark-materials

In the *His Dark Materials* trilogy, each person in Lyra's world has a daemon, which seems to be a part of their soul.  Where do these daemons come from?  Are they birthed by other daemons or do they appear spontaneously when a human baby is born?

Comment: We're never given any details about the birth/first appearances of daemons, but since they're manifestations of a person's soul, I'd imagine that they magically appear at the birth of a person.

Comment: I  vaguely recall something about being generated by/manifested from Dust?

Comment: I think it is mentioned somewhere that they just appear. I imagine it like the way they disappear when their human dies, but in reverse. In fact, it wouldn't make sense for them to be birthed by other daemons because it would suggest that human and daemons are two "equal" parts of a being, while everything else in the stories treats the humans as central and the daemons as peripheral, though extremely important.
This is, obviously, just interpretation, and I don't have the energy to reread all the books for a quote right now, that's why I'm posting this as a comment (sorry for that :/)

Answer (score 8):

A daemon is part of a person's soul.  While I have no proof from the books here, it seems pretty obvious that they just appear when the baby is born.  Consider the case of people in worlds where daemons are not physical forms, like Will.  his daemon is born within him, as part of him, and only later manifests itself.  So it seems only logical that they are born at the same time as the rest of them.  Think of human and daemon as one being, not two.

Answer (score -3):

I would say that when the baby is born, their dæmon is born along side them, from the human mother, so the baby has her/his dæmon while he/she is growing in the mom's womb. I have no proof for this, it's just how I like thinking about it. They're born together, they live together and they die together.

Comment: On SFF we prefer answers that are backed in evidence rather than just wild stabs in the dark. If you do find some evidence at some point please come back and [edit] it into your answer.